# UDP receive data

Tags: java, udp

I'm programming about UDP in Mac with IntelliJ Idea.I tried to read data from client and print data that server receive.Here's the code.

`Server`

```
public class UDPServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(11111);
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(b,1024);

        while (true){
            datagramSocket.receive(datagramPacket);

            byte[] data = datagramPacket.getData();
            InetAddress address = datagramPacket.getAddress();
            String ip = address.getHostAddress();
            String string = new String(data,0,data.length);
            System.out.println("IP is "+ip+" "+string);
        }
    } }
```

`Client`

```
public class UDPClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String dataString;
        while((dataString = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            if(dataString.equals("886")){
                System.out.println("UDPClient exit");
                break;
            }
            DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(dataString.getBytes(),dataString.getBytes().length, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.3.2"),11111);

            datagramSocket.send(datagramPacket);

        }

        datagramSocket.close();
    }

}
```

I ran the `Server` first and then started the `Client`,and input something.Here's the input and print.

`input`

123456

abcdef

hello

`print`

IP is 192.168.3.2 123456����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������

IP is 192.168.3.2 abcdef����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������

IP is 192.168.3.2 hellof����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������

1.the thrid print has another 'f'

2.at the end of every print there are many little squares(I don't have enough reputation to insert picture,sorry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here in the server code:

```
String string = new String(data,0,data.length);
```

You're constructing a String based on the entire size of the data buffer, not the number of bytes received.  As a result, if a packet is smaller that the last one, any additional bytes from that packet are still in the buffer.

You need to call `datagramPacket.getLength()` to get that value:

```
String string = new String(data,0,datagramPacket.getLength());
```

Comment: I got it.And Could you have a look at this picture?[print](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxejIA_xra_SQVFBT0hsSE9mcXM/view?usp=sharing).The squares are so strange.

Comment: Those are probably non-printable characters from the buffer.  Is that still happening after applying the above fix?

Comment: It's OK after applying the code.Thanks very much.^_^